# Use of Position in Adaptable Priority Queue

Tags: java, data-structures

What is the use of Position in Adaptable priority queue(List based heap for keys)  when we have to anyway pass the Entry reference to the functions remove(k), replaceKey(k).
i.e. If I have some reference "ref" to an entry in queue then I can simply call remove(ref) and replaceKey(ref) and that would still take O(1) time. Why would I need special position for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It doesn't make any sense at all to implement a heap as a linked list. Heaps are inherently neally complete binary trees. You can store a heap in an array because it's easy to compute the array index of a node's children: the children of the node at position i live at positions 2i + 1 and 2i+2. It's massively more efficient to find the ith element of an array than the ith element of a linked list.
2. For adaptable priority queues, The array(heaps) is a sequence of references to position instances, each of which stores a key, value, and the current index of the item within the array. The user will be given a reference to the Position instance for each inserted element.When we perform priority queue operations on our heap, and items are relocated
   within our structure, we reposition the position instances within the array and we
   update the third field of each position to reflect its new index within the array, and the update will take O(log(n)) time complexity.